# Embed player HTML5 like

Tags: php, html

What can i use to do something like HTML5 player for browsers that don't support html5? 
Like IE8 and others..

I need for a project, my marketing want to sent a link for all peopple, but some still use WinXP with IE8.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: HTML5 player for **what**?  Audio?  Video?  What exactly are you doing?  What are your project requirements?

Comment: Audiojs did the job. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Video for Everybody Generator](http://v4e.thewikies.com/)  for html video with some fallback options like flash etc 
also there is [videojs](http://videojs.com/) css & js player framework